# Adding Qt Sources to QtCreator 2.4.1

Tags: qt, qt4, gdb, qt-creator

I am currently using QtCreator 2.4.1 with Qt 4.7.4 development libraries (in Ubuntu) and am trying to track down a bug which after profiling with valgrind seems to occur internally within QGraphicsView::paintEvent(…) method

To help isolate this problem I would like to step into the Qt sources. Having done some searching through both the Qt forums and stack overflow and have not being able to find a way to integrate the sources with my version of QtCreator.

I have currently tried downloading the sources via the QtSDK manager and adding a “Source Path Mapping” within Tools->Options->Debugger. I am sure that this step is where I am making a mistake as I am unable to even switch to source when viewing internal Qt header files i.e. from QGraphicsView.h

I have so far tried adding the following Source Path Mappings

`Source Path=/var/tmp/qt-src
TargetPath=/home/paul/QtSDK/QtSources/4.7.4`

and

`Source Path=/var/tmp/qt-src
TargetPath=/home/paul/QtSDK/QtSources/4.7.4/src`

Neither works.

I have also tried building Qt directly from source, adding this to my "Qt versions" list  within Qt Creator and creating a new project configuration using this version. This also did not work.

Likewise I have tried adding the src folders to my gdbinit file. This also fails to work.

I am completely lost with this.

Paul

Comment: If you use GDB manually, can you step into it? Do the installed versions of Qt have debug symbols (e.g. built with SplitDebug)?

Answer (score 6):

Someone asked a similar question here: [Need to step into Qt sources (my IDE is Qt Creator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049578/need-to-step-into-qt-sources-my-ide-is-qt-creator).

Someone else asked about Valgrind errors with Qt here: [Suppression files for Qt memory leaks with Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174326/suppression-files-for-qt-memory-leaks-with-valgrind)

And here is a little more info about [Using Valgrind with Qt Creator](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_valgrind_with_Qt_Creator) along with some explanation about how to read the results.  Its a little dated from late 2010.

### Related Suggestions

- I wouldn't debug the QGraphicsView class just because of all the effort to make it work or find the problem might be for nothing... Qt is moving to using the [SceneGraph](http://qt-project.org/videos/watch/scene_graph_a_different_approach_to_graphics_in_qt) as the backend for QML and the rendering engine for QGraphicsView might become obsolete.
- Updating to the latest stable build of the Qt libraries may make a big difference for QGraphicsView.
- If you post the valgrind error you are getting to the [Qt Trolls](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa), someone might be able to explain what is going on for you.
- There are other debugging techniques besides the traditional debugger.  I've been programming in Qt in Windows (without valgrind) and with a large multi-threaded application, that loads a bunch of Dll's.  I've had to put some faith into the [Object Tree Model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html) clean up and work on all the `new` calls I put in.  Most of the time I just use QDebug to find errors.  Then I am also using a combination of [`qInstallMessageHandler()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtglobal.html#qInstallMsgHandler) with [`QDebug`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdebug.html) to implement decent logging for the hard to track bugs.

See also [Qt Debugging Techniques](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/debug.html).