# Minimal Qt program makes memory leak

Tags: qt, memory-leaks

Here is a nearly minimal Qt program, which should release all the resources, including the memory:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    std::unique_ptr<QWidget> wnd{new QWidget()};
    wnd->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

However, `valgrind` says that:

```
LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 979 bytes in 24 blocks
   indirectly lost: 7,858 bytes in 56 blocks
     possibly lost: 912 bytes in 19 blocks
   still reachable: 75,719 bytes in 1,080 blocks
                      of which reachable via heuristic:
                        newarray           : 832 bytes in 16 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
```

I expected to get zeros for "definitely lost" and "indirectly lost", but have got lost bytes. Why? Do I interpret `valgrind` output incorrectly, or should I call some additional exit function of Qt?

Comment: You're code is excessive. Don't hold widgets/`QObject`s by pointer unless you have a good reason to. A `QWidget`, like all other PIMPL-using Qt objects, the size of a `void*`. **Hold it by value**.

Comment: Yes,, Qt leaks that memory because it's silly to waste CPU cycles on releasing it when you're terminating the process anyway. As far as I'm concerned, it should leak way more: every of those deallocations are a waste. You need to add the non-freed allocations as exceptions to Valgrind. These are single-time allocations, they don't accumulate over time. They happen on startup and are completely normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better reformulation of the question is: "valgrind suppress qt errors". There is a number of recipes, also here on stackoverflow, for example:

Suppression files for Qt memory leaks with Valgrind
[Suppression files for Qt memory leaks with Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174326/suppression-files-for-qt-memory-leaks-with-valgrind)

The answer refers to this document from wxWidgets: Valgrind Suppression File Howto https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Valgrind_Suppression_File_Howto

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistaken assumption that "correct/proper/whatever your goodness metric is" code will leak no memory.

There are two kinds of leaked memory: startup, or one-time allocations that won't ever be repeated, and ongoing leaks from allocations that can be repeated an arbitrary and ever-increasing number of times. The latter are understandably problematic and should be fought viciously until they perish.

On the contrary, **it is absolutely, no-qualms-about it wasteful** to free startup memory. Every CPU cycle devoted to it wasted when the very next thing to happen is process termination where all the memory is released in the most cycle- and energy-efficient way possible. These allocations aren't leaks. They are on *you* to add to your memory debug tool's exception list.

The cultish freeing of every single block of memory right before process termination has a measurable impact on energy efficiency of applications that are executed multiple times in rapid succession. For common short-lived processes such as many Unix core utilities and build tools, including compilers, the `free`s prior to exit have wasted many railcar-loads of coal in power plants all over the world, and this trend shows no signs of slowing down.

Valgrind is a godsend. But you can't treat its output with veneration best afforded a finer deity. Don't develop software based on Valgrind's output as if it was a cargo cult. Understand what the output means, and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion, but the question is not if the lack of leaks is good or bad, the question is how to get zero leaks in a Qt application. Anyway, thanks to your comments, I've derived the better formulation of the question: "valgrind suppress qt errors", and immediately got an answer.

Comment: @olpa You do not want zero leaks. You want zero leaks *in Valgrind's report*. There's a big difference between these two.